# Missing Content After Migrating from iPhone 7 Plus to iPhone 11. What is the best way to rectify?

Tags: iphone, ios, icloud

I recently got a new iPhone 11. I went through the setup which included, I thought, a migration of all my data from my old iPhone 7 Plus using `transfer directly from iPhone`.  By data I mean photos/videos, text and apps.  What I found was that the newest stuff is missing.  Maybe like 3 years of data.  Probably some other stuff missing also.

For a long time on my iPhone 7 Plus I ignored the "`iCloud is full, please upgrade`" messages. I never upgraded, staying on the free tier.  I suspect that this might be the root cause of this problem.  As if the phone data migration was based on the iCloud.  Does this make sense?

I have been on my new phone for about a week?

If this does make sense, then what is my best path forward?  My ideas:

- Go back to my old phone, upgrade the iCloud tier. Allow the backup to
  happen then sync devices.  Thereby syncing (copying) the content on
  the iCloud to my new iPhone 11.
- Or restore my last backup of my iPhone 7 Plus to my iPhone 11.

Do you think my iCloud situation was the cause of this?
Other possibilities?
What is the best to get my content to my iPhone 11?

Comment: Do you have a Mac or a Windows computer? (i.e. you could make an encrypted backup on the computer and restore that to the new phone - thus not requiring the purchase of any additional iCloud storage space)

Comment: Yes - windows.  Thank you.  I think I will pursue that idea.